# What's wrong with this proof? if $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Proof:

Since $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0 $ so there exists $M > 0$ such that $a_n < M$ for all $n$.

Also, there exists $N$ such that for all $m,n \geq N$ we get $|\sum_{k=n}^m |b_k|| < \epsilon/M$

thus $$|a_nb_n + \dots + a_mb_m| \leq |a_nb_n| + \dots + |a_m||b_m| \leq M(|b_n| +\dots +|b_m|) < M  \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon$$ So by the cauchy principle, convergence follows.

I think that my proof is wrong, but I don' see the error, I think it's wrong because  I only used the convergence of $\sum a_n$ to deduce that $a_n$ goes to $0$. so that hypothesis is unnecessary,  according to my proof, it's enough for $a_n$ to be bounded. so $a_n$ doesn't even need to be convergent.  Can someone point out the mistake please? I've tried to find a counter example but I haven't found any yet.

Comment: Your proof (as well as your comment on possible generalizations) is indeed correct.

Comment: If $(a_n)$ is bounded and $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely then so does $\sum a_nb_n$. You can be absolutely sure about this -:)

Comment: I missed the bit where you require that (at least) one of them converges absolutely.  My example was irrelevant for that reason.

Comment: So I guess my professor wrote $\sum a_n$ convergent to make it easier for us or something, I'm insecure about writing proof. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: For a quicker proof (assuming that the comparison test has been established), you may argue that the right-hand side of $$\sum_n |a_n b_n|\leq \Bigl(\sup_n |a_n|\Bigr)\sum_n |b_n|$$ is finite, and so, $\sum a_n b_n$ converges absolutely. This is an instance of the far-reaching generalization called the [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only flaw is in the 1st sentence,where $a_n<M$ should be $|a_n|<M.$